# Proof of $1/x^2$ being uniformly continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for $a>0$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

When I try to prove this I find that $$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{y^2}|<|\frac{1}{a^2}|+|\frac{1}{a^2}|=\frac{2}{a^2} $$
I can't see how to proceed by here, how can I get $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$ given the above line?

Comment: You need to use the fact that you can have $|x-y|<\delta$ for some $\delta$.

Comment: @Alan That's what I find tricky, how can I use this information to inform my choice of $\delta$?

Comment: Don't immediately go to that extreme, you need to stay in $x$ and $y$ for a bit.   Expand the subtraction

Comment: Another simple approach is to use the mean value theorem. What you end up using is that the derivative of $x\mapsto 1/x^2$ is bounded on $[a,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comment,  $$\left|\frac 1 {y^2} - \frac 1 {x^2}\right|=\left| \frac {y^2-x^2}{x^2y^2}\right|=\left| \frac {(y-x)(y+x)}{x^2y^2}\right|=|y-x|\left| \frac {y+x}{x^2y^2}\right|$$

We can make $|y-x|$ small,  so the key is that you now need to be able to bound $\left| \frac {y+x}{x^2y^2}\right|$ by a constant.  Can you manage that?

Comment: Well $|\frac{y+x}{x^2y^2}|\le\frac{|y+x|}{a^4}$ but how can we bound $|y+x|$?

Comment: You can split the fraction up first before bounding it to get rid of the numerator